# C# - Setting multiple image objects onto a form

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner at c# and i was wondering what's causing the error here. I'm trying to set a width, height, dock or image in an object.

```
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileNo = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\images\Products\productListing.txt");
    PictureBox[] imageControl = new PictureBox[fileNo.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNo.Length; i++)
    {
        imageControl[i].Width = 400;
        imageControl[i].Height = 400;

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"..\..\images\Products\" + i + ".jpg");

        imageControl[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        imageControl[i].Image = (Image)image;

        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a nullreferenceexception was unhandled error on

```
imageControl[i].Width = 400;

imageControl[i].Height = 400;

imageControl[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

imageControl[i].Image = (Image)image;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not instantiating any `PictureBoxes`.  Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileNo.Length; i++)
{
    imageControl[i] = new PictureBox();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create `PictureBox` class object then assign these properties. You are just trying to access picturebox but you have haven't initiated that object.

```
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileNo = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\images\Products\productListing.txt");
    PictureBox[] imageControl = new PictureBox[fileNo.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNo.Length; i++)
    {
        imageControl[i] = new PictureBox(); // initiate object first
        imageControl[i].Width = 400;  // you are accessing a null object here.
        imageControl[i].Height = 400;

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"..\..\images\Products\" + i + ".jpg");

        imageControl[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        imageControl[i].Image = (Image)image;

        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

If you want to add these Picture controls to the form then add them using the Form.Controls proertry.
e.g.
this.Controls.Add(imagecontrol[i]. but remember you are setting these control Dock property to Fill then you will only able to see only on image at once. So set their size and location property to show them all one.

Hope this help you..